# Parallax image not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to used this plugin: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ but unfortunately I can't get it to work. What's my mistake?

```css
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="parallax.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://mikeysiegel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/nasa-cosmos-4.jpg" data-speed="0.2" data-bleed="10" data-natural-height="332" data-natural-width="1000"></div>
 <div style="background-color: red;">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Background image loaded and parallax worked good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="parallax.js"></script>
```

The above code contains the problem. `"parallax.js"` isn't stored anywhere. If you change the url into an URL, linking to the `"parallax.js"` file, it will work. Now, the url is redirected to `"http://stacksnippets.com/parallax.js"`. At this url **isn't** any file

---

Example:

```js
/*!
 * parallax.js v1.3.1 (http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/)
 * @copyright 2015 PixelCog, Inc.
 * @license MIT (https://github.com/pixelcog/parallax.js/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

  // Polyfill for requestAnimationFrame
  // via: https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

  (function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
      window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame']
                                 || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
      window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
          timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
      };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
      window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
        clearTimeout(id);
      };
  }());


  // Parallax Constructor

  function Parallax(element, options) {
    var self = this;

    if (typeof options == 'object') {
      delete options.refresh;
      delete options.render;
      $.extend(this, options);
    }

    this.$element = $(element);

    if (!this.imageSrc && this.$element.is('img')) {
      this.imageSrc = this.$element.attr('src');
    }

    var positions = (this.position + '').toLowerCase().match(/\S+/g) || [];

    if (positions.length < 1) {
      positions.push('center');
    }
    if (positions.length == 1) {
      positions.push(positions[0]);
    }

    if (positions[0] == 'top' || positions[0] == 'bottom' || positions[1] == 'left' || positions[1] == 'right') {
      positions = [positions[1], positions[0]];
    }

    if (this.positionX != undefined) positions[0] = this.positionX.toLowerCase();
    if (this.positionY != undefined) positions[1] = this.positionY.toLowerCase();

    self.positionX = positions[0];
    self.positionY = positions[1];

    if (this.positionX != 'left' && this.positionX != 'right') {
      if (isNaN(parseInt(this.positionX))) {
        this.positionX = 'center';
      } else {
        this.positionX = parseInt(this.positionX);
      }
    }

    if (this.positionY != 'top' && this.positionY != 'bottom') {
      if (isNaN(parseInt(this.positionY))) {
        this.positionY = 'center';
      } else {
        this.positionY = parseInt(this.positionY);
      }
    }

    this.position =
      this.positionX + (isNaN(this.positionX)? '' : 'px') + ' ' +
      this.positionY + (isNaN(this.positionY)? '' : 'px');

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) {
      if (this.iosFix && !this.$element.is('img')) {
        this.$element.css({
          backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.imageSrc + ')',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundPosition: this.position
        });
      }
      return this;
    }

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android)/)) {
      if (this.androidFix && !this.$element.is('img')) {
        this.$element.css({
          backgroundImage: 'url(' + this.imageSrc + ')',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundPosition: this.position
        });
      }
      return this;
    }

    this.$mirror = $('<div />').prependTo('body');
    this.$slider = $('<img />').prependTo(this.$mirror);

    this.$mirror.addClass('parallax-mirror').css({
      visibility: 'hidden',
      zIndex: this.zIndex,
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      overflow: 'hidden'
    });

    this.$slider.addClass('parallax-slider').one('load', function() {
      if (!self.naturalHeight || !self.naturalWidth) {
        self.naturalHeight = this.naturalHeight || this.height || 1;
        self.naturalWidth  = this.naturalWidth  || this.width  || 1;
      }
      self.aspectRatio = self.naturalWidth / self.naturalHeight;

      Parallax.isSetup || Parallax.setup();
      Parallax.sliders.push(self);
      Parallax.isFresh = false;
      Parallax.requestRender();
    });

    this.$slider[0].src = this.imageSrc;

    if (this.naturalHeight && this.naturalWidth || this.$slider[0].complete) {
      this.$slider.trigger('load');
    }

  };


  // Parallax Instance Methods

  $.extend(Parallax.prototype, {
    speed:    0.2,
    bleed:    0,
    zIndex:   -100,
    iosFix:   true,
    androidFix: true,
    position: 'center',
    overScrollFix: false,

    refresh: function() {
      this.boxWidth        = this.$element.outerWidth();
      this.boxHeight       = this.$element.outerHeight() + this.bleed * 2;
      this.boxOffsetTop    = this.$element.offset().top - this.bleed;
      this.boxOffsetLeft   = this.$element.offset().left;
      this.boxOffsetBottom = this.boxOffsetTop + this.boxHeight;

      var winHeight = Parallax.winHeight;
      var docHeight = Parallax.docHeight;
      var maxOffset = Math.min(this.boxOffsetTop, docHeight - winHeight);
      var minOffset = Math.max(this.boxOffsetTop + this.boxHeight - winHeight, 0);
      var imageHeightMin = this.boxHeight + (maxOffset - minOffset) * (1 - this.speed) | 0;
      var imageOffsetMin = (this.boxOffsetTop - maxOffset) * (1 - this.speed) | 0;

      if (imageHeightMin * this.aspectRatio >= this.boxWidth) {
        this.imageWidth    = imageHeightMin * this.aspectRatio | 0;
        this.imageHeight   = imageHeightMin;
        this.offsetBaseTop = imageOffsetMin;

        var margin = this.imageWidth - this.boxWidth;

        if (this.positionX == 'left') {
          this.offsetLeft = 0;
        } else if (this.positionX == 'right') {
          this.offsetLeft = - margin;
        } else if (!isNaN(this.positionX)) {
          this.offsetLeft = Math.max(this.positionX, - margin);
        } else {
          this.offsetLeft = - margin / 2 | 0;
        }
      } else {
        this.imageWidth    = this.boxWidth;
        this.imageHeight   = this.boxWidth / this.aspectRatio | 0;
        this.offsetLeft    = 0;

        var margin = this.imageHeight - imageHeightMin;

        if (this.positionY == 'top') {
          this.offsetBaseTop = imageOffsetMin;
        } else if (this.positionY == 'bottom') {
          this.offsetBaseTop = imageOffsetMin - margin;
        } else if (!isNaN(this.positionY)) {
          this.offsetBaseTop = imageOffsetMin + Math.max(this.positionY, - margin);
        } else {
          this.offsetBaseTop = imageOffsetMin - margin / 2 | 0;
        }
      }
    },

    render: function() {
      var scrollTop    = Parallax.scrollTop;
      var scrollLeft   = Parallax.scrollLeft;
      var overScroll   = this.overScrollFix ? Parallax.overScroll : 0;
      var scrollBottom = scrollTop + Parallax.winHeight;

      if (this.boxOffsetBottom > scrollTop && this.boxOffsetTop < scrollBottom) {
        this.visibility = 'visible';
      } else {
        this.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
      this.mirrorTop = this.boxOffsetTop  - scrollTop;
      this.mirrorLeft = this.boxOffsetLeft - scrollLeft;
      this.offsetTop = this.offsetBaseTop - this.mirrorTop * (1 - this.speed);

      this.$mirror.css({
        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
        visibility: this.visibility,
        top: this.mirrorTop - overScroll,
        left: this.mirrorLeft,
        height: this.boxHeight,
        width: this.boxWidth
      });

      this.$slider.css({
        transform: 'translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)',
        position: 'absolute',
        top: this.offsetTop,
        left: this.offsetLeft,
        height: this.imageHeight,
        width: this.imageWidth,
        maxWidth: 'none'
      });
    }
  });


  // Parallax Static Methods

  $.extend(Parallax, {
    scrollTop:    0,
    scrollLeft:   0,
    winHeight:    0,
    winWidth:     0,
    docHeight:    1 << 30,
    docWidth:     1 << 30,
    sliders:      [],
    isReady:      false,
    isFresh:      false,
    isBusy:       false,

    setup: function() {
      if (this.isReady) return;

      var $doc = $(document), $win = $(window);

      $win.on('resize.px.parallax load.px.parallax', function() {
          Parallax.winHeight = $win.height();
          Parallax.winWidth  = $win.width();
          Parallax.docHeight = $doc.height();
          Parallax.docWidth  = $doc.width();
          Parallax.isFresh = false;
          Parallax.requestRender();
        })
        .on('scroll.px.parallax load.px.parallax', function() {
          var scrollTopMax  = Parallax.docHeight - Parallax.winHeight;
          var scrollLeftMax = Parallax.docWidth  - Parallax.winWidth;
          Parallax.scrollTop  = Math.max(0, Math.min(scrollTopMax,  $win.scrollTop()));
          Parallax.scrollLeft = Math.max(0, Math.min(scrollLeftMax, $win.scrollLeft()));
          Parallax.overScroll = Math.max($win.scrollTop() - scrollTopMax, Math.min($win.scrollTop(), 0));
          Parallax.requestRender();
        });

      this.isReady = true;
    },

    configure: function(options) {
      if (typeof options == 'object') {
        delete options.refresh;
        delete options.render;
        $.extend(this.prototype, options);
      }
    },

    refresh: function() {
      $.each(this.sliders, function(){ this.refresh() });
      this.isFresh = true;
    },

    render: function() {
      this.isFresh || this.refresh();
      $.each(this.sliders, function(){ this.render() });
    },

    requestRender: function() {
      var self = this;

      if (!this.isBusy) {
        this.isBusy = true;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          self.render();
          self.isBusy = false;
        });
      }
    }
  });


  // Parallax Plugin Definition

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      var options = typeof option == 'object' && option;

      if (this == window || this == document || $this.is('body')) {
        Parallax.configure(options);
      }
      else if (!$this.data('px.parallax')) {
        options = $.extend({}, $this.data(), options);
        $this.data('px.parallax', new Parallax(this, options));
      }
      if (typeof option == 'string') {
        Parallax[option]();
      }
    })
  };

  var old = $.fn.parallax;

  $.fn.parallax             = Plugin;
  $.fn.parallax.Constructor = Parallax;


  // Parallax No Conflict

  $.fn.parallax.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.parallax = old;
    return this;
  };


  // Parallax Data-API

  $(document).on('ready.px.parallax.data-api', function () {
    $('[data-parallax="scroll"]').parallax();
  });

}(jQuery, window, document));
```

```css
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://mikeysiegel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/nasa-cosmos-4.jpg" data-speed="0.2" data-bleed="10" data-natural-height="332" data-natural-width="1000"></div>
 <div style="background-color: red;">
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here, the `"parallax.js"` is located inside the snippet, and it will load succesfull. Now, it works with no problems...